# How to use Google's One Tap sign-in UI without resorting to deprecated API

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, google-one-tap

The following code is copied from [Google's official document](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials) about how to use One Tap sign-in UI for Android:

```
oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signUpRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                            result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender(), REQ_ONE_TAP,
                            null, 0, 0, 0);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
```

You can see they use deprecated `startIntentSenderForResult`.
I have the following:

```
final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncherGoogleDriveSignIn = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
           ...
        }
);
```

I cannot figure out how to replace `startIntentSenderForResult` with the above `activityResultLauncherGoogleDriveSignIn`.

Any tip will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult instead of registerForActivityResult this will take a parameter of Intent sender request see the code below

```
ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK){
                    // plug the code from google's official documentation
                }
            }
    );
```

and just launch it whenever user click on signin using google

```
launcher.launch(new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender()).build());
```

the whole code looks like this

```
// the user clicks the login button
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signUpRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
                    .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                            .setSupported(true)
                            .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                            .build())
                    .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
                    .build();

            oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signUpRequest)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(LoginPageActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
                            launcher.launch(new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender()).build());
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(LoginPageActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // No Google Accounts found. Just continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

// the result of clicking the button
ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK){
                    try {
                        SignInCredential credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.getData());
                        String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
                        if (idToken != null) {
                            AuthCredential firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
                            mAuth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                            } else {
                                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    } catch (ApiException e) {
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```